# adding a character into string and printing it prints gibberish in C

Tags: c, string, char, character, puts

So I have this function:

```
void function (linked_list first, char character){
    linked_list new = NULL;
    new = (linked_list) malloc(sizeof(linked_list));
    new->name[0] = character;
    puts (new->character);
    ...
```

My problem is that this puts prints out my character followed by some garbage, for example if `character = t`, puts will print tőú or something like that.

So my question would be, how do I put a char to an end of a string, without it messing up everything? Oh, and name is defined inside a structure as char name[256];

Comment: We don't know what your `linked_list` structure (correction, whatever structure a `linked_list` points to) looks like; in particular, we don't know what `new->character` is. Or are you really calling `puts(new->name)`? If so *please* update your question so you're showing us your actual code (copy-and-paste it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string in C needs to be terminated. So you want to do

```
new->name[0] = character;
new->name[1] = '\0';
```

Otherwise you will see all the "gibberish" that was in memory (malloc doesn't clear the memory, so it's pointing to "whatever was there").

Not also the excellent point made by @self - you are not allocating enough memory for the structure, but only for the pointer to the structure.  And in modern C (anything after C89, really) you don't cast the result of malloc - that's "old K&R" (I know, because it's what I learnt...). These days you should just write

```
new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
```

By using `sizeof(*new)` you guarantee that the size will be right, even if you change your mind about the type of `new` in the future... It is the cleanest way to do this (and a nod to @WhozCraig who pointed this out in a comment).

Answer (score 1):

`puts` expects strings to be null terminated.

If you're just copying one character in to the string, add a null terminator:

```
new->name[0] = character;
new->name[1] = '\0';
puts (new->name);
```

Comment: As Keith Thompson commented, I'm assuming you meant `puts (new->name)`, not `puts(new->character)`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming linked_list is a typedefed pointer( it must be since you cast your malloc with it ) then your malloc is allocating only enough space for a pointer. You should be allocating space for the entire struct.

```
new = (linked_list) malloc(sizeof(*linked_list));
```

Comment: Good catch! Amazing how many mistakes one can make in three lines of code.

Comment: Even better if you throw out that cast. And better still if you used `sizeof(*new)`.

Comment: @WhozCraig I kept the original style.

Comment: Yes - and the original style has gone out of fashion about 15 years ago. I know, because I have the original K&R that still has that syntax...

Comment: @Floris The answer should is primarily directed towards OP, and using his style will increase the chances of understanding.

Comment: @self - I consider SO an opportunity for continuous learning. I learnt (from folks like H2CO3 and WhozCraig) about many bad habits I had (kept) in 20+ years of writing code. Now I try to pay it forward by passing on the lessons I learnt. Yes irrelevant to the question; but maybe helpful in a broader sense. Question of personal style, I suppose.

Comment: @Floris I should have used old and new way and compare+explain, but didn't because too lazy.